# Add row in form with textareas [php]

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, row

I want to add new row in form but i can't. After clicking btn add nothing is happen. If i change  tag to  then i can add a row but it's badlooking and not correctly i think.

This is my Javascript:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 2;
            var rowTemplate = jQuery.format($("#template").val());
            function addRow(){
                var ii = i++;
                $("#list tbody").append(rowTemplate(ii));
                $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
                    $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                });
            }
            $(".add_row").click(addRow);
        });
```

This is my html:

```
<table id="template" style="display:none;">
                <tr id="row_{0}">

                    <td><input type="text" size="20" name="numer[]"></td>
                    <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="tresc[]"></textarea></td>
                    <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="zmianaZapisu[]"></textarea></td>
                    <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="uzasadnienie[]"></textarea></td>
                    <td><img src="/../_img/row_del.png" id="delete_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table id="list">
                <thead >
                    <tr>
                        <th>Numer jednostki <br />redakcyjnej</th>
                        <th>Treść</th>
                        <th>Proponowana zmiana brzmienia zapisu <br />lub treść nowego zapisu</th>
                        <th>Uzasadnienie</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type ="text" size="20" name="numer[]"></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="tresc[]"></textarea></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="zmianaZapisu[]"></textarea></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="uzasadnienie[]"></textarea></td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

$oForm->formHTML('<div class="add_btn_block"><div class="row_add_btn add_row">Dodaj wiersz harmonogramu</div></div>');
$oForm->formHTML(addRows());
```

I have no clue what may be wrong, but something is. Can you help me?

EDIT:

After help row adding works but form looks bad.

This is how it should looks like:

[image]

And this is how it looks like now:
[image]

How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
                var i = 2;
                var rowTemplate = $("#template").html();
                function addRow(){
                    var ii = i++;
                    $("#app_here").append(rowTemplate); // changed from '#list tbody' to '#app_here'
                    $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
                        $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                    });
                }
                $(".add_row").click(addRow);
            });
    </script>

    <table id="template" style="display:none;">
                    <tr id="row_{0}">

                        <td><input type="text" size="20" name="numer[]"></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="tresc[]"></textarea></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="zmianaZapisu[]"></textarea></td>
                        <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="uzasadnienie[]"></textarea></td>
                        <td><img src="/../_img/row_del.png" id="delete_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="list">
                    <thead >
                        <tr>
                            <th>Numer jednostki <br />redakcyjnej</th>
                            <th>Treść</th>
                            <th>Proponowana zmiana brzmienia zapisu <br />lub treść nowego zapisu</th>
                            <th>Uzasadnienie</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th> <!-- Added this column as you have image column -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type ="text" size="20" name="numer[]"></td>
                            <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="tresc[]"></textarea></td>
                            <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="zmianaZapisu[]"></textarea></td>
                            <td><textarea style="resize:both;" name="uzasadnienie[]"></textarea></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td> <!-- Added this column as you have image column -->
                        </tr>
<!-- HTML will be appended here now.. -->
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5" id="app_here">

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

You have appended  as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</table>
```

which is not a proper way.. I've added `<tr><td> HEre table will be appeneded </td></tr>`..
Check my html portion of code..

Answer (score 1):

You have used  `$("#template").val()`

`.val()` only works on form elements.

Try changing it to

```
 $("#template").html()
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works but the form looks bad now. I edited my post and show how it looks like. Do you know whats wrong now?

Comment: Can you create a quick fiddle with the code you have problem with?
http://jsfiddle.net